# Javascript: How turn every n number of characters into items in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an string that I would like to turn into an array, taking every 3 characters in the string as an item in that array. For example"

```
var theString = "hello there!"

// the resulting array will look like this
["hel", "lo ", "the", "re!"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
var theString = "hello there!";
var arr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < theString.length; i+=3) {
  arr.push(theString.substring(i, i+3));
}
```

Comment: I tried this in the console, `arr` comes back as: 
`["hel", undefined × 2, "lo ", undefined × 2, "the", undefined × 2, "re!"]`

Comment: Ah right - that's because only arr[0], arr[3], arr[6] (etc.) exist due to arr[i] incrementing by three after every iteration of the for loop. `Array.push()` can also be used, and it will add values to the end of `arr[]`. I updated my answer to reflect this.